# How to modify PySimpleGUI code for recording video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video, pysimplegui

I have created application for video camera with PySimple GUI.
Though recording starts, I cannot open the recorded file.

Codes for recording is as follow:

```
elif Record:
        cv2.destroyWindow('Camera View')
        while True:
            # get data
            ret, frame = camera.read()
            # date
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame,strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"),(10,30), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.imshow('Record Window', frame)
            video.write(frame)
            #RecordStop True
            event, values = window.read(timeout=20)
            if event == 'RecordStop':
                break
        cv2.destroyWindow('Record View')
        CameraOn = True
        Record = False
```

I think that "Camera App."  window interupts the recording because I can successfuly record a video if I don't use GUI.

I would like to know how to change the code.
All the code is as follows.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import strftime

windowname = "Camera View"

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# layout
sg.theme('BluePurple')
layout = [[sg.Text('Operation:'),sg.Text(size=(15,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],[sg.Button('CameraOn'), sg.Button('CameraOff'), sg.Button('Record'), sg.Button('RecordStop')]]


# Show Window
window = sg.Window('Camera App.',layout, location=(800, 400))

# Movie FIle
fps = int(camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))                    # Get FPS
w = int(camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))              # Get Width
h = int(camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))             # Get Height
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')        # mp4
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', fourcc, fps, (w, h))  # (File Name,fourcc, FPS, Size)

CameraOn = False
Record = False

#　Event Loop
while True:
    #　Get Event
    event, values = window.read(timeout=20)
    #　"CameraOn"
    if event == 'CameraOn':
        CameraOn = True
        Record = False

    #　"CameraOff"
    elif event == 'CameraOff' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        CameraOn = False
        Record = False
        break
    
    #　"Record"
    elif event == 'Record':
        CameraOn = False
        Record = True
    
        
    #　CameraOn True
    elif CameraOn:
        # get data
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        frame_num = camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

        # date
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame,strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"),(10,30), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        
        # show
        cv2.imshow(windowname, frame)

    #　Record True
    elif Record:
        cv2.destroyWindow('Camera View')
        while True:
            # get data
            ret, frame = camera.read()
            # date
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame,strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"),(10,30), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.imshow('Record Window', frame)
            video.write(frame)
            #RecordStop True
            event, values = window.read(timeout=20)
            if event == 'RecordStop':
                break
        cv2.destroyWindow('Record View')
        CameraOn = True
        Record = False


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Finish Program")
```

Comment: [mre] is required. if this is an issue with using OpenCV, remove all irrelevant stuff (pysimplegui) -- very likely a duplicate question. where do you `.release()` the writer object?

Comment: In statement `if ... elif ... else`, only one case executed, not all cased meet requirements executed.

Comment: The program works when I add "video.release()" after "if event == RecordStop'"! Thank you very much!